# How to convert time to bigdecimal with ruby?

Tags: ruby, time, bigdecimal

For example, I have a time data with string format:

```
00:25:23;16
```

I want to convert it to `BigDecimal` and tried:

```
a = '00:25:23;16'.to_d
=> #<BigDecimal:96cb548,'0.0',9(18)>
```

When I check a:

```
a.floor
=> 0
```

It looks not the true value. Then how to convert it the right way?

## Addition

I expect the bigdecimal value like this(Maybe not a right value):

```
1543.123
```

Comment: What sort of output do you expect? A UNIX timestamp? What is the part after the `;` (`;16`)?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I expect data like this format: `1543.123`(It's not the right value).

Comment: It would be helpful to show the result you want for your example string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `;16` means milliseconds then maybe you are looking for this?

```
> str = "00:25:23;16"
=> "00:25:23;16"
> h, m, s, ms = str.split(/[:;]/).map(&:to_f)
=> [0.0, 25.0, 23.0, 16.0]
> h * 3600 + m * 60 + s + ms/1000
=> 1523.016
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is what I want. Thought it looks a little complexity, I can use it now:)

Comment: ...and use [BigDecimal::new](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-c-new) to return a Big Decimal: `require 'bigdecimal'; BigDecimal.new(h * 3600 + m * 60 + s + ms/1000) #=> #<BigDecimal:7fad011a9e50,'0.1523016E4',18(36)>`.

Comment: Sorry, here `;16` means timecode.  So do you know how to change it to second?

Comment: can anybody explain how to do it in java?